# Use of tense and clause in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> 'when ***shone*** through a prism, a beam of white light breaks into all
>   the colours of the rainbow'

Is the usage of *shone* correct here? Is it an adverb clause?

Answer (score 3):

I think that "shone" is correct here, but it sounds a bit old fashioned. For more on shone vs shined, you could see this:

http://grammarist.com/usage/shined-shone/

"shone" in your sentence is a passive participle from "shine," and it is part of an adverb clause.

Some English teachers will tell you not to write in the passive voice very often.

Comment: Perhaps I'm showing my age, but I can't really endorse that "a bit old-fashioned". According to NGrams, both [**shone a light** and **shined a light**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shone+a+light%2Cshined+a+light&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshone%20a%20light%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshined%20a%20light%3B%2Cc0) have been *gaining* traction in the past few years. But I still think the latter sounds more "ignorant" than "modern".

Comment: @Fumble - You've _shone_ your age again ;^)

Comment: @J.R. *Sho **'nuff**, massa!*

Comment: I agree with Fumble - there's nothing old-fashioned about shone. In fact "shined" still sticks in my craw to some extent when I hear it and I have to remind myself that it's a valid form. Furthermore, in terms of the passive, "very often" is relative. The passive has a place in English and should obviously be used correctly, but to limit its frequency is ludicrous. In my answer, I recommended an active variant, but not because I consider the passive marked or incorrect in any way.

Answer (score 2):

**shone** works. So do **passed** and **directed**.

Alternatively, you may opt to not use the passive voice at all:

> When a beam of white light **passes** through a prism...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the usage of "shone" in your example is correct. In this case, the use of "shone" versus "shined" is a matter of personal preference.